# Relative Layout XConstraint & YConstraint Vs. WidthConstraint & HeightConstraint in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, android-relativelayout

What's the difference between XConstraint and WidthConstraint or YConstraint and HeightConstraint when using Relative layout in Xamarin.Forms?
It seems like they both serve the same purpose and they can be used interchangeably. Here's an example from Microsoft's documentation.

```
<RelativeLayout>
<BoxView Color="Red" x:Name="redBox"
    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
        Property=Height,Factor=.15,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.8,Constant=0}" />

<BoxView Color="Blue"
    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
        ElementName=redBox,Property=Y,Factor=1,Constant=20}"
    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
        ElementName=redBox,Property=X,Factor=1,Constant=20}"
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=.5,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.5,Constant=0}" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: [XF RelativeLayout doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout) starts with a description of these 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are different.

`XConstraint` – decide the x (horizontal) position of the view's anchor

`YConstraint` – decide the y (vertical) position of the view's anchor

`WidthConstraint` – decide the width of the view

`HeightConstraint` – decide the height of the view

Each of those values are set as a proportional value in [RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout).